# Head Block não carrega ficheiro CSS

Tags: css, magento

Eu criei um *block* para carregar os arquivos *CSS*:

```
<block type="page/html_head" name="head" as="head">
  <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/base.css</stylesheet></action>
  <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/topo.css</stylesheet></action>
  <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/rodape.css</stylesheet></action>
  <!--<action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/reset.css</stylesheet></action>-->
</block>
```

e no diretório *CSS* eu tenho estes arquivos:

```
base.css
reset.css
rodape.css
topo.css
```

`base.css` carrega beleza, `topo.css` também mas `rodape.css` não carrega.

Alguma dica?

Comment: com certeza não deve estar chamando ela de forma correta, algum erro ortográfico ou de abertura/fechamento das tags. qual o site?

Comment: Está em localhost. Mas por descartar as possibilidades de erro de grafia que eu postei o conteúdo do diretório CSS. Observe que o base.css carrega mas o rodape.css não.

Comment: Agora está acontecendo outro lance: Eu apontei um footer.phtml, preenchi o arquivo e foi beleza. Após uns dias eu retirei o comando que importa este footer.phtml mas o rodapé que eu criei não some.

Comment: Isso pode ser problema de cache do Magento.

Comment: E o quê eu poderia fazer para contornar?

Comment: Lembre-se sempre de apagar a pasta /var/cache do magento caso contrario sempre acontecerá esse tipo de problemas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente como reference ao invés de block

```
<reference name="head">
  <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/base.css</stylesheet></action>
  <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/topo.css</stylesheet></action>
  <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/rodape.css</stylesheet></action>
  <!--<action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/reset.css</stylesheet></action>-->
</reference>
```